# How do I check whether a Vector exists and has already been defined in Java?

Tags: java, vector

I'm attempting to check whether vector.isEmpty() before looping through it but sometimes the vector hasn't even been defined yet because it gets assigned within a function somewhere else. Is there a way to check whether `vector == Vector` before trying to invoke any Vector methods on said vector?

I'm coming from a JavaScript background and because of its loosely typed system, I can simply do `if (isArray(array))`. Is there any similar or standard procedure for checking whether a Vector has been defined before operating on it?

Comment: `vector != null`?

Comment: I tried that and it threw an error saying "attempted to compare a Vector type with type null." There is a definition of vector at the top of the class such that `protected Vector<User> vector;` but it isn't assigned until later: `vector = new Vector<User>();`

Comment: we need to see the code.... post your code please

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, I think check it against null does actually work. I swear I remember it throwing an error last night. Maybe I got confused as there were a lot of errors. XD Thanks you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
if(myVector != null) {
    // let's work with it!
}
```

for this. In Java it must have been declared earlier, e.g. `Vector myVector`.

Also, note that Vector is quite an old collection. `ArrayList` might be the more suitable fit unless you have particular concurrency considerations in play?